# Rewriting a set of propositions that includes a circular proposition

Tags: logic

> "For any proposition P, if I believe that P then this paragraph (everything that is written between the quotes) entails that I believe that P.
>   I believe that I exist.
>   For any proposition P, if I believe that P then I believe that I believe that P.
>   For any proposition P, if I don't believe that P then I believe that I don't believe that P."

How can I write a set of propositions that doesn't include circular propositions and is logically equivalent to the set of propositions that are in the quotes?

Comment: The issue with what you are doing is that the symbolism in Math can be vague because the standards for what counts as a proposition has been lost. Almost any nonsense would qualify as a proposition today whereas in classical logic this would never happen. In Mathematical logic to state P alone expresses the truth value of the variable p is TRUE.To Express p is false there is another way to write that.  You are adding belief which has no place in deductive reasoning.  You can't have circular propositions. Those aren't propositions anymore.Only one proposition counts even if you repeat it.

Comment: @Logikal Isn't there an entire modal logic built to reason deductively about beliefs?

Comment: @Logikal "the symbolism in Math can be vague because the standards for what counts as a proposition has been lost ... Almost any nonsense would qualify as a proposition today" Huh? That's a strong claim, can you back it up at all?

Comment: @Daniel  prendergast, modal logic is not pure deductive reasoning. Pure deductive reasoning defines proposition in a certain way which allows only two truth values. The famous LAWS OF THOUGHT are also based on a two value system. When you start adding stuff you are including Psychology and other sciences to a subject that is in a different category.  That would be like comparing a dance to a song. Both are not in the same category and sub categories.

Comment: @Noah Schweber, I don't know exactly what you mean by back it up at all. Well of you were aware that Mathematical logic did not exist until the 19 century you would know definitions shifted towards math.  How do you define proposition? I bet you lean towards math. Find an old philosophy text that defines proposition loosely for me. Find any older text that defines a proposition as a sentence for me. Those influences came from mathematicans. Medevial logicians did not accept anything as a proposition nor did they use symbolization for propositions.

Comment: @Logikal Well, some modal logics are non classical, but when you say "model logic" you think of classical modal logic, which absolutely is bivalent. And non bivalent logics are still deductive

Comment: The intent of inventing Mathematical logic does not hold with deception. It works when all people are being nice, truthful & honest perhaps. It works sometimes in reality and sometimes it doesn't. How are you to know when the argument applies to reality & when it doesn't? Mathematical logic claims validity is about form alone which make it a trivial subject. You do things just because you are free to do them. Classical logic was not like this nor was it a trivial exercise. Propositions had to be evaluated as either true or false to take an argument SERIOUSLY.

Comment: @DanielPrendergast You might want to read some of the other answers by Logikal on this site - if their last couple comments didn't make it clear, they're not exactly arguing in good faith (and I'm bowing out at this point.)

Comment: "Math was not invented to argue in the same sense lawyers would argue or activist for a cause would argue. That is closer to Rhetoric than math" if that'ds true, then Maths influence on logic can only be a good thing for philosophers. We want to be more precise and rigorous than activists in our argumentation

Comment: **Back to the point**?  You cannot remove self-reference that is genuinely present and preserve the logical content.  The referential links are part of the logical content.  If you change the links between assertions, you change the meaning.  Your best bet is actually to find someting slightly stronger, that turns the specific self-reference into a global reference, principle or axiom.  But that will then mean slightly more than the original.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original set of propositions:

> "For any proposition P:
>   If I believe that P then this paragraph (everything that is written between the quotes) entails that I believe that P.
>   I believe that I exist.
>   If I believe that P then I believe that I believe that P.
>   If I don't believe that P then I believe that I don't believe that P."

If I believe that P then from that alone I can derive by reiteration that I believe that P.  What may be intended are the following three statements:

1. For all P if I believe that P then I believe that I exist.
2. For all P if I believe that P then I believe that I believe that P. [[modal axiom 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic#Axiomatic_systems) and [normal reasoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxastic_logic#Types_of_reasoners) in doxastic logic or [principle of positive introspection]](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/#PrinKnowBeli)
3. For all P if I don't believe that P then I believe that I don't believe that P. [principle of negative introspection]

If that paraphrasing actually means what one intended to say, then it would be a way around the circularity.

Comment: Your set of propositions doesn't entail that I believe anything because all of its propositions have "if I believe that P" at their start and it could be that for any P I don't believe that P.

I'm going to assume that in proposition number 1 you meant to write: "I believe that I exist.". 
Even then your set of propositions doesn't entail that I don't believe that cats exist, whereas my set of proposition entails that I don't believe that cats exist
(Subtitute P by "cats exist" in the contrapositive of my first proposition.)

Comment: @avraham I think what you have in the first line is "I believe that P". If I added that then you would get by reiteration "I believe that P". I agree that I don't think the three propositions would entail "I believe that P" nor would the assumption "I believe that P" entail these three propositions. Also my first one included "I believe that P" because I assumed that was the antecedent of all of these propositions. I am not sure what it is the argument is trying to show so I offered a paraphrase of what I thought it meant.